# ChangeEventListner and checked items

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a form with a combobox and a list of radiobutton that change when the value of combobox change.
This works correctly the problem is that when I open this form passing an object it doesn't checked the values found into the database!

This is a part of the code:

```
comboBox.setDataProvider(comboBoxDataProvider);
comboBox.setEmptySelectionAllowed(false);
comboBox.setItemCaptionGenerator(ComboBox::getName);
comboBox.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        ComboBox f=(ComboBox)(event.getSource().getValue());
        radioButton.setItems(ComboBoxService.getInstance().getListRadioButtonByComboBox(f.getId()).stream());
    }
});
radioButton.setDataProvider(radioButtonDataProvider);
radioButton.setItemCaptionGenerator(RadioButton::getName);

binder = new BeanValidationBinder<>(Entity.class);
binder.forField(comboBox).bind("comboBox");
binder.forField(radioButton).bind(Entity::getRadioButton, Entity::setRadioButton);
binder.bindInstanceFields(this);
```

As I said, this code workswell without the changeEventListner (obviously will return all radio button's items and change the items if there is the changeEventListner; These situations mean, for me, that the first time set correctly the checked items but, when subselect the radio button's items, it lost this information!
Someone can help me?

I'm using Vaadin8 and java1.8 ...

As requested:

```
public synchronized Set<RadioButton> getListRadioButtonByComboBox(int idComboBox) {
    EntityManager entityManager = JpaUtil.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    ComboBox comboBox= null;
    try {
        comboBox= entityManager.find(ComboBox.class, idComboBox);
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
    return comboBox.getRadioButtons();
}
```

so I must add that I'm using also Hibernate 5.2 to manage persistence layer!

Comment: For the future readers: I wrote the code surronding with <code> tag but I could not submit the question because it was bad indended ... I'm blind and the only solution that I found is the deletion of the tag! So tell me where is the problem and not give me a -1 only for that! thanks in advance.

Comment: The binder does set a new value for the checkbox, which triggers you valuechanged code. Simplest workarround is to add the valueChangeListener ``after`` binding it.

Comment: @André-Schild : thank for your suggestion but doesn't work ...

Comment: Perhaps swap the binder for comboBox and radioButtons? There is not enough code to see what the getListRadioButtonByComboBox() functions does and how it knows which checkbox is associated

Comment: @André-Schild  : I added the method getListRadioButtonByComboBox ... please see if, for you, could be a problem in this simple method ...